# Using EmberJS in metalsmith.IO

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, ember.js, ember-cli, codesmith

I need to use EmberJS within an already existing codesmith.IO project that previously was using Angular 1. I feel like I'm missing something simple in terms of implementing that, and since I've always used Ember CLI to generate the template for a new app I'm a bit lost in terms of what is actually needed for Ember to run within an enviroment like codesmith which is a regular static site generator.

If anyone could enlight me on where I'm overcomplicating the implementation in my head I'd be more than grateful :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Ember without Ember CLI is somewhat deprecated. You can still download prebuilt `ember.js` files from https://emberjs.com/builds/release, but it is recommended to use Ember CLI instead whenever possible.

If you want to use an Ember app in a static site generator you would likely develop the app in a subfolder with Ember CLI. Whenever you change something build it using `ember build -prod`, then copy the resulting `vendor.js` and `your-app.js` files into a folder of your static site generator and finally include them using `<script>` tags.